# Create an array of pointers to maps in stack memory, if possible

Tags: c++, arrays

So, as the title explains, I need to declare an array of pointers to maps.

An example:

```
map<int,int>* mp[10] ; 
mp[0] = new map<int,int>() ;
mp[0][0] = 21 ;
cout<<mp[0][0]<<endl ;
```

Gives the error:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
main.cpp:15:16: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘std::map’ and ‘int’)
     mp[0][0] = 21 ;
```

Okay. So this means that `mp[0][0]` is a map, and not the 0th map in `mp`, for which we're putting the value of 0 as 21. So this means that `mp[0]` is an array of maps. This means that the statement `map<int,int>* mp[10]` actually creates an array of arrays.

> So, what is `mp[0] = new map<int,int>()` doing? Is it not creating an object of the type `map<int,int>` in heap, and putting it in `mp[0]`?

This is confusing me, and questioning my basics. How should I create an array of pointers?

When I do:

```
map<int,int>* mp = new map<int,int>() ;
mp[0][21] = 99 ;
cout<<mp[0][21]<<endl ;
```

It works fine. How do I make a pointer to an object of `map`? And how do I create an array of these pointers to objects?

Any help is appreciated.

---

**Why this savagery?**

Use case: There's a graph o f say size `n`. Now I need to merge maps for all the children of a node. Now there's a `bigChild` which is the child, which has the subtree of maximum size. That is `subtree(bigChild)>=subtree(other children)`.

There's a HLD (heavy light decomposition) concept of merging smaller children's data into the data of the big child, and bam, you get the answer for the current node (the parent of these all children).

The data structure that saves the answers is a map. So, I have to create an array of maps of size `n`. Now for the `mp[node]`, I need to add the information of the smaller children, and merge them into the `mp[bigChild]`. That is, we don't want to add the data of`mp[bigChild]` to some other map. Instead, we want to add all data into it, so that time complexity is O(n lg n).

That means we assign `mp[bigChild]` to `mp[bigChild]`. If I'd declared `map<int,int> mp[10]`. Then `mp[node] = mp[bigChild]` would have copied all the members of `mp[bigChild]`, which we do not want. So, instead, `mp[node]` should point to `mp[bigChild]`. And then we add the data of the smaller children to the this map.

I hope this helps.

Comment: No, `mp` *is* an array of pointers, `mp[0]` is a pointer to a map, and `mp[0][0]` is equivalent to `*mp[0]`, which is a map. `mp[0][0][0] = 21;` or `(*mp[0])[0] = 21;` would work.

Comment: There is no line 15 in the code in the question. Post real code.

Comment: In your first example, `mp[0]` is a `map<int, int>*`, so the working syntax would be `(*mp[0])[0] ` or simplier (imo) `mp[0]->at(0)`

Comment: This kind of structure is exactly what I'd suggest to someone that I don't like. Seriously, you *can* do stuff like that in C++, but you'd probably be better of not doing it. If you present the background/rationale for that approach, you might get better suggestions.

Comment: why all those pointers? Dynamically allocating a standard container is almost always not necessary (/wrong). If you want an array of maps you should use a `std::array<map_type,10>` or a vector when the size is dynamic

Comment: I agree completely:  "This is ***C++,*** not C!"  You have a rich variety of standard container-types available to you, and you should leverage these instead of monkeying around with pointers.  They're fast, they're efficient, and they're debugged.  The compiler can also now catch more stupid-mistakes at compile time.

Comment: If you think you need `new` to "construct an object" you are *flat wrong*

Comment: @Caleth What else should I use? AFAIK `new` returns a pointer to an object created in the heap memory.

Comment: @MikeRobinson Agreed. But without this monkeying around, I never would have understood these concepts. I am really sorry for wasting the time of so many people, but I hope this question helps other people understand what's really going on under the hood.

Comment: `std::map<int,int> mp[10];` creates 10 maps. `std::vector<std::map<int, int>> mp(1);` creates one map in something that can hold arbitrarily many maps

Comment: @Caleth Aah. Yeah yeah. Actually the use case is of creating dynamic maps when necessary. That's why the _pointers_ to the maps. I have a memory constraint. Long story short, it's a CP question.

Comment: @PeteBecker Trust me. I never lie.

Comment: It's not about lying. It's about readers being able to reproduce the problem. The code as written does not produce that error message, although it has a host of other problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So this means that mp[0][0] is a map and not the 0th map in mp

`mp` does not contain maps. It contains pointers to maps.

> So this means that mp[0] is an array of maps.

It does not mean that. `mp[0]` is the pointer at index 0 of the array.

> This means that the statement `map<int,int>* mp[10]` actually creates an array of arrays.

That declares an array of pointers.

> So, what is mp[0] = new map() doing? Is it not creating an object of the type map in heap, and putting it in mp[0]?

It creates a dynamic object of type `map<int,int>` indeed. But that object is not "put" into `mp[0]`. The object is in the free store. What is stored in `mp[0]` is a pointer to the object.

> How should I create an array of pointers?

You've already created an array of pointers successfully. What you've failed to do is indirect through the pointer within the array to access the map  - From another perspective, you've accidentally indirected through the pointer by using the subscript operator when you presumably attempted to use the subscript operator of the map:

```
mp[0][0] = 21 ;
   ^  ^    ^
   |  |    Assignment of value 21 into map; ill-formed
   |  index 0 of pointer; type: map
   index 0 of array; type: pointer
```

Following would be correct:

```
mp[0][0][0] = 21 ;
   ^  ^  ^    ^
   |  |  |    Assignment of integer; OK
   |  |  The value mapped to key 0; type: int
   |  index 0 of pointer; type: map
   index 0 of array; type: pointer
```

However, it is somewhat confusing to access a singular object through a pointer using the subscript operation. Following is more conventional:

```
 (*mp[0])[0] = 21 ;
```

To understand the equivalence, remember that `a[b]` is same as `*(a + b)` for pointers. Therefore `a[0]` is same as `*a`.

---

P.S. There is hardly ever a need to allocate a `std::map` dynamically. It would be simpler and more efficient to create an array of maps instead of an array of pointers to maps.

P.P.S You leak the dynamic map. Avoid bare owning pointers (i.e. don't allocate dynamically unless you need to, and when you need to do so, use smart pointer).

Comment: You got me at the efficient part. You're compelling me to post the use case. On it Sir.

Comment: Added the background.

Answer (score 4):

> So this means that mp[0] is an array of maps. This means that the statement map* mp[10] actually creates an array of arrays.

Your statement is wrong. Pointers and arrays in C++ are close related (it comes from C) so:

```
pointer[0]
```

is equal to

```
*(pointer + 0) // or even
*pointer
```

which does not mean that this pointer points to an array of elements. So in your code you use additional [0] as a unreadable equivalent of dereference and your statement:

```
mn[0][0] = 25;
```

is equal to:

```
*(mn[0]) = 25;
```

which obviously have issues - assigning integer to a `std::map`, it should be:

```
(*mn[0])[0] = 25;
```